# Menu bar is covering the Deletion pop-up

Tags: bug, design

[image]

The "Recommend Deletion"  pop-up is not fully visible.

Yes, this is a minor bug, but it looks clean it this is fixed.

Comment: Experienced this as well often enough, and yes i agree this is something which could be better. Since so i added the feature suggestion tag to your post.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your screen resolution?

Comment: @Adam 1366x768 :D

Comment: This also applies to other dialogs, e.g. the flag / close one, which can also show / be moved to under that top bar.