# The yellow "question has been deleted" bar is underneath the Ubuntu navbar when scrolling

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

When scrolling down, the "this question has been deleted" bar is partially hidden under the Ubuntu navigation bar:

[image]

I think the z-index ordering should be done in such a way that the yellow popup bar shows up *above* the Ubuntu navbar, not below it. This is somewhat related to [Menu bar is covering the Deletion pop-up](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15506/menu-bar-is-covering-the-deletion-pop-up).

Comment: `z-index: 10000000000000000000000000000;` FTW.